# Get a gameobject to copy a target position and rotation with velocity/angularvelocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have an `gameobject` that I need to follow (have the same orientation an position) another `gameobject` by changing only the `velocity` and `angularvelocity`.
For the position it's easy :

```
    clone.velocity = (target.transform.position - clone.transform.position) * k;
```

But for the `angularvelocity` I don't find, it seems that I need to use `Quaternion.FromToRotation` with something like that :

```
    Vector3 oldpoint = clone.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
    Vector3 newpoint = target.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
    var av=Quaternion.FromToRotation(oldpoint,newpoint);
```

but it returns a `quaternion` and `angularvelocity` is a `vector3`, I don't find how to convert it.

Comment: Wait you don't want to `have the same orientation an position` but rather move smoothly towards it right? ;)

Comment: for the angular velocity you can simply use `av.eulerAngles * somefactor`!

Comment: @derHugo No I want the same position and rotation. I'll try with eulerAngles...

Comment: If you want the same positon and rotation both objects will overlap. In this case you could just use `MovePosition` and `MoveRotation` ...

Comment: You also know btw that instead of `TransformDirection(Vector3.up)` you could simply use `transform.up` ;)

Comment: @derHugo MovePosition is not configurable and seems to have a factor that limit the move speed. Thankyou for the tips for `transform.up`. About eulerAngles it goes from 0 to 360, then I need to remove 180 when greater than 180.

Comment: @Entretoize `angles %= 180;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html):

```
Vector3 oldpoint = clone.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
Vector3 newpoint = target.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up);
Quaternion av = Quaternion.FromToRotation(oldpoint,newpoint);

float angle;
Vector3 axis;

av.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);

// Convert to signed angle
angle = Mathf.Repeat(angle + 180f, 360f) - 180f;

// depending on how rapidly you want it to rotate to match it 
// don't set too high or it might overshoot
float angularVelocityFactor = 0.01f; 

clone.angularVelocity = (angularVelocityFactor * angle) * axis;
```

Comment: Your true except that angle need to be converted in radian and that as it returns a positive angle (0 to 360) you have to minus 360 when larger than 180 : `if (angle > 180)    angle -= 360;     angle *= Mathf.Deg2Rad; ` can you correct and I'll accept your anwser.

Comment: @Entretoize I'm surprised `ToAngleAxis` will give `angle` greater than 180. I edited my answer to convert `angle` to signed equivalent. Anyway, converting specifically to radians is unnecessary. Instead, use a smaller `angularVelocityFactor` value.